# Plotting GPS velocity field and ellipse error in QGIS 3.26.1

Tags: qgis, gps, ellipse

I am a beginner in QGIS and I do not know how I can plot a GPS velocity field as well as ellipse errors (text file) in QGIS. How can I do this?

Comment: I suggest you provide more details on your data and your desired outcome. Have you done any research on how to achieve your goal, or similar outcomes?

Comment: Maybe these links gets you started? https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/importing_spreadsheets_csv.html and https://guides.library.duke.edu/QGIS/Symbolize